# Regular expression to find word with in word in php

Tags: php, regex

The below PHP regular expression will match the string which contain GB:2 and the word Samsung also there with in three word.

But my data sometimes contain GB-2 or GB,3 etc. So I want to change my regular expression as GB* so that it will take any character and alphabet after GB.

How I can put this GB* in my regular expression?

```
$regex = "~(?i)\bGB:2 (?:\w+\s+){1,3}Samsung\b~";
```

Comment: http://regexpal.com is a great place to test your regex.

Comment: Give us some example that which should match against the regex.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/nR0iG6 please have a look at this

Comment: Your test example doesn't provide all of the needed combinations that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is what you're looking for - http://regex101.com/r/qJ9dV0

```
(?i)([0-9]GB|GB)[!@#$%^&*() _,.:-]\w+ (?:\w+\s+){1,3}application
```

EDIT You have to remove the boundaries and be a little more literal in your selection. I have made an improvement that will also get GB preceeded by numbers or just GB - http://regex101.com/r/jH7rH0 (You will need to add a dash to the special characters group as I just noticed that in your text. It has been correctly added in this answer.)

Comment: Please have  a look at this http://regex101.com/r/gD1fF1,  Some place it contain Gb-2 or Gb,2s like that

Comment: How can I match any character or alphabet after GB

Comment: To match any character or alphabet you would insert that in the brackets following, just as I have done in the example.

Comment: great, this is what I want